# Starting delayed_job with Dokku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, docker, dokku

I'm using Dokku and the [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) gem, and I'm trying to start the process like this:

```
dokku run APP_NAME bin/delayed_job start RAILS_ENV=production
```

But no jobs are registered, and when I do this:

```
dokku run APP_NAME bin/delayed_job restart RAILS_ENV=production
```

I get `Warning: no instances running. Starting...`

However, if I start the the proccess with:

```
dokku run APP_NAME rake jobs:work
```

It works... But only as long as I'm logged in to the server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So this is how I got it to work:

I installed the [Dokku Shoreman plugin](https://github.com/statianzo/dokku-shoreman) and then created a `Procfile` in the apps root folder like this:

```
web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
worker: bundle exec rake jobs:work
```

Now everything works like it should.